# C# - How to add a Percentage Reading to a ProgressBar

Tags: c#, .net

I have looked at various sources on the internet regarding this, but they all seem a little extreme.

I currently have a `ProgressBar` in a *Windows Form*. Although I would like to have a percentage reading on it.

**My Solution:** label1.Text = e.ProgressPercentage + "%";

Comment: do you have a question?

Comment: @Bueller How do you add percentage to a progress bar?

Comment: edit the question to include that - and anything else that might help us give you an answer.

Comment: Solution: label1.Text = e.ProgressPercentage + "%";

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's no longer recommended to put text within a progress bar.

> [image]
>
> Source: [Windows UI Guidelines for Progress
>   Bar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn742475.aspx)

Instead, place a label above or below the progress bar with such information as percent completion, estimated time remaining, time elapsed, and current action.

Comment: Solution: label1.Text = e.ProgressPercentage + "%";

Comment: Do you have a reference to this recommendation?

Comment: @Charles Graham http://www.debugging.com/bug/23495

Comment: @charles: I sure do, added link to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using the Control.CreateGraphics().DrawString() method.
[MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring.aspx)

You would call this method after setting the progress bar's value.