# How to get the percentage from ProgressBar and pass it to the "label.text"?

Tags: c#, progress-bar

In program, percantages from progressbar is not showing.
[image: img2]

but, when I traced it, the "label.text" has the values.
[image: img1]

Thankyou!

Comment: Looks like you are setting the text in a loop. Note that the UI will only be redrawn when there is time to do so, i.e. when your method completes.

Comment: Please, red this: [How to make thread-safe calls to controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-make-thread-safe-calls?view=netdesktop-5.0)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c# progress bar percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14350533/c-sharp-progress-bar-percentage) and [C# - How to add a Percentage Reading to a ProgressBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480853/c-sharp-how-to-add-a-percentage-reading-to-a-progressbar) and [Calculating the progress percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217393/calculating-the-progress-percentage) and [Adding percentage text to progressbar C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33809509/adding-percentage-text-to-progressbar-c-sharp)

Comment: You didn't provide a reproducible example. You didn't indicate the technology you are using (is this a web application? A WinForms/WPF app?). The small piece of code you you posted is an image, which is also a bad practice. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and improve your question.

Comment: @GyörgyKőszeg Thanks for your advice! I'am using WinForms btw.

Comment: Thanks for @OlivierRogier, this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33809509/adding-percentage-text-to-progressbar-c-sharp is worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should use async programming, i write a simple example with button, progress and label to simulate progress update.
When click on button the progress starts updating .

```
 private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     var c = 0;
     // 100 is progress max value for example
     while (c < 100) {
        await Task.Delay(500);
        this.progressBar1.Value = c++;
        // Set label!
     }
  }
```